# Creating a ComboBox/Drop Down Type UserControl in WPF

Tags: wpf, user-controls

How can I ComboBox/Drop Down Type User Control. I want to have a control where a TextBox is displayed by default, then when the user clicks/focuses the textbox, have a "Drop Down" appear that contains a bunch of other controls, when the textbox/usercontrol loses focus eg. user clicks elsewhere, the "Drop Down" should disappear

Comment: What's wrong with the built-in combobox?

Comment: +1 as @OJ said. Why re-inventing wheel? But, you still want to customize text box. Consider Popup http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx

Comment: @OJ, @Avatar, I don't want to reinvent the wheel too, but suppose I want to create something more complex like a color/date picker I guess it may not be easy to use a Combobox?

Comment: if you want to this to be in a UserControl level, still the best option is using Combo Box.:) If you want it to be more versatile, then, as I mentioned earlier, you can use Popup control. It would be handy. If you want more information on this particular, reflecting some 3rd party controls such us ColorPicker or DateTimePicker would give some nice insight about this.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

AutoCompleteTextBox in WPFToolkit

http://wpf.codeplex.com/